# How to enable a Cassandra node to participate in multiple cluster?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I want to use Cassandra cluster for some specific purpose across data centers. What I want to figure out is how can I enable a single Cassandra node to participate in multiple clusters at the same time? I googled it, however I could not find any use case of Cassandra as I mentioned above. Is this possible with the current architecture of Cassandra?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. By design all nodes in Cassandra cluster ate equal. I think Cassandra designers had that very goal in mind and wanted to depart from MongoDB architecture where you have several different kinds of nodes. So, all nodes are equal, thus no way to have "special purpose" node even in a single cluster.